# Check if record exists in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have the following 3 tables

**Source**

```
Id | Name         | SiteId
---+--------------+---------
1  | Source 1     | 1
2  | Source 2     | 1
3  | Source 3     | 2
4  | Source 4     | 2
```

**SourceAccount**

```
SourceId | AccountId
---------+----------
1        | 1
2        | 1
3        | 1
4        | 1
```

**SourceUser**

```
SourceId | UserId
---------+----------
1        | 1
3        | 1
```

I'm trying to build up a query with thew following parameters

- SiteId (1)
- AccountId (1)
- UserId (1)

With those parameters the query should return something like this

```
SourceId | Name         | Access
---------+--------------+---------
1        | Source 1     | 1
2        | Source 2     | 0
```

Access column being a boolean (bit)

So in essence the query should return all the sources (Id and Name) that are part of a given AccountId for a given SiteId along with a boolean telling me is a user has access to it or not.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Thanks

EDIT:
For the record here is the query I came up with but does not work:

```
 SELECT s.[Id], s.[Name]
      ,(IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[SourceUser] su WHERE su.SourceId = s.[Id] AND su.UserId = 1)
            SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE
            SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT))
  FROM [dbo].[Source] s
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[SourceAccount] sa ON sa.SourceId = s.Id
  WHERE sa.AccountId = 1
  AND s.SiteId = 1
```

Might also be worth mentionning that I'm running this on SQL Azure and SQL Server 2012

EDIT 2: Relations

```
      SiteAccount - Site - SiteUser - User
      |                 \               |
Account - SourceAccount - Source - SourceUser
```

Comment: its not entirely clear how the three tables relate, you have four sources that each relate to account 1 are the column heading correct? but my thoughts are you should be using a left outer join

Comment: Something doesn't add up here, both Source 1 and Source 2 are related to site id 1 and account id 1, and where does the user fit in your tables?

Comment: I actually stripped out the Account and User tables. In fact sources are parts of sites and available for accounts and within accounts available to only certain users

Comment: Account - SourceAccount - Source - SourceUser - User
Account - User

Comment: Wow that does not look like anything... Will add it in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.[Id],
       s.[Name],
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[SourceUser] su WHERE su.SourceId = s.[Id] AND su.UserId = 1)
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
       END AS Access
 FROM [dbo].[Source] s
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[SourceAccount] sa ON sa.SourceId = s.Id
 WHERE sa.AccountId = 1 AND s.SiteId = 1
```

Comment: I keep wasting time setting up sqlfiddles, I should've just started on the query first :D here you go though http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/755a0/2

Comment: AccountId is not part of SourceUser so in the case, I can't have su.AccountId = 1

Comment: So AccountId becomes UserId. I get results with this, I'll verify if that works on multiple cases but that looks to be nice like this

Comment: Yes, just change AccountId to UserID in case statement. Edited.

Comment: I confirm it works all fine! Will accept the answer and try to add the extra tables as shown in EDIT 2. Thanks